# Which tag can be used to break the execution of flow in certain conditions?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am unable to break the execution of flow while scripting in pace automation framework. Please suggest the other way or suggest any tag to break execution of flow in certain condition

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This tag can be used to finish the flow in certain conditions.

```
Syntax:
<finishFlow/>
```